# Need help to optimize handling data from Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, optimization

So I'm trying to get the data from my Database to export to a third-party source. I have all my items separate for specific reasons on how I process my data.

Though they are similar but not the same. Though the third-party source doesn't care if they are at least similar in one way which is their SKU.

So I need to condense my data to count all items with the same SKU. So make the array smaller but now it has quantity added.
 so like `[{SKU:1234},{SKU:1234},{SKU:1234},{SKU:1234}]` TO `[{SKU:1234, quantity:4}]`

The way I do it is quite slow and can't think of a better way to do it off the top of my head v.v

```
router.get("/export", Auth, async (req, res) => {
  let AllProducts = await Products.find({
    store: req.decoded.user.storeid,
    shipped: false,
    pullsheet: { $ne: true }
  }).sort("sku");


  let dupArray = [];
  let csvArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < AllProducts.length; i++) {
    let noMatch = true;
    for (let d = 0; d < dupArray.length; d++) {
      if (AllProducts[i].sku === dupArray[d].sku) {
        if (dupArray[d].quantity) {
          dupArray[d].quantity = dupArray[d].quantity + 1;
        }
        noMatch = false;
        console.log(dupArray[d]);
        let removed = AllProducts.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
        d = dupArray.length;
      }
    }
    if (noMatch) {
      let removed = AllProducts.splice(i, 1);
      removed[0].quantity = 1;
      dupArray.push(removed[0]);
      i--;
    }
  }

  res.send(dupArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the result you want with an aggregation pipeline such as this:

```java
db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      store: "1",
      shipped: false,
      pullsheet: false
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$sku",
      qty: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      SKU: "$_id",
      quantity: "$qty",
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { SKU: 1 }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-AkLvKUPYTr